# On diagonal part of tensor product of $C^*$-algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, tensor-products

Suppose we have a $C^*$-algebra  $\mathcal{U}$, Consider the $C^*$-subalgebra generated by elements of the form $a\otimes a$, what is it isomorphic to? Is it isomorphic to $\mathcal{U}$ itself?

Comment: I don't think you necessarily get anything nice in general, probably since the map $a \mapsto a\otimes a$ isn't linear. However, you will in certain special cases get something nice if you look at particular "diagonal" type $C^\ast$-algebras. For instance, if $G$ is a discrete group, let $D$ be the $C^\ast$-subalgebra of $C^\ast_r(G) \otimes_{\max{}} C^\ast_r(G)$ generated by the elements $u_g \otimes u_g$ for $g\in G$. An easy consequence of Fell's absorption is that $D\cong C^\ast(G)$.

Comment: What topology do you put on your tensor product $C^* $ algebra ?

Comment: (Nota also that the name diagonal would have been better suited for maps of shape $a \otimes b \mapsto ab$)

Comment: @Bleuderk minimal tensor product say

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get the symmetric part of the tensor product.

The map $\phi: a\otimes b \mapsto b\otimes a$ extends to an order 2 automorphism of $\mathcal{U}\otimes\mathcal{U}$. The set of fixed points for this $\mathbb{Z}/2$ action is a C*-subalgebra $(\mathcal{U}\otimes\mathcal{U})_s$ of $\mathcal{U}\otimes\mathcal{U}$. Every $x \in \mathcal{U}\otimes\mathcal{U}$ can be written as $x = \frac{1}{2}(x + \phi(x)) + \frac{1}{2}(x - \phi(x))$, expressing it as $y + z$ where $\phi(y) = y$ and $\phi(z) = -z$, i.e., every element is the sum of a symmetric part and an antisymmetric part.

The C*-subalgebra generated by $\{a\otimes a: a \in \mathcal{U}\}$ is clearly contained in $(\mathcal{U}\otimes\mathcal{U})_s$, and conversely, it contains, for any $a,b \in \mathcal{U}$, the element $a\otimes b + b \otimes a = (a+b)\otimes (a+b) - a\otimes a - b\otimes b$. From here one can show inductively that this C*-algebra contains everything in the algebraic tensor product that is fixed by $\phi$. Then anything in the tensor product is the limit of a sequence of elements of the algebraic tensor product, and taking symmetric and antisymmetric parts as above shows that any symmetric element is approximated by symmetric elements of the algebraic tensor product. Thus you get all of $(\mathcal{U}\otimes\mathcal{U})_s$.

For instance, if $\mathcal{U} = C(X)$ then you get the symmetric continuous functions in $C(X\times X)$.

Comment: Does $(\mathcal{U}\otimes \mathcal{U})_{s}$ has faithful state?

Comment: Well, every separable C*-algebra has a faithful state. If $\mathcal{U}$ doesn't have a faithful state then $(\mathcal{U}\otimes\mathcal{U})_s$ won't either.

Comment: I mean product state restricted on $({\mathcal{U}\otimes\mathcal{U}})_{s}$

Comment: The question I am interested to ask you that if I start with a faithful state on $\mathcal{U}$, does the product state is also faithful $(\mathcal{U}\otimes \mathcal{U})_{s}$? If you know any article regarding these please refer!! It is my urgent request.

Comment: If $\phi$ is faithful on $\mathcal{U}$ then $\phi\otimes\phi$ is faithful on the full spatial tensor product $\mathcal{U}\otimes\mathcal{U}$, and hence also on its symmetric part. That's very easy if you just work in the GNS representation.

Comment: for higher powers still the diagonal part of tensor algebra is still fixed point algebra of flip automorphism? My question what will happen for higher powers regarding my same question applies?

Comment: Further, the antisymmetric part of $\mathcal{U}\otimes\mathcal{U}$ does not have the identity, then what will be its GNS space?

Comment: I think you need to work some of these things out yourself.

Comment: Okk, surely. But I see myself the general case well.